# Embedded Reporting Service is unavailable in Bluemix Catalog

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to use Embedded Reporting Service in my app. to geenrate a report around DashDB. I am following this article for that -

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/analytics/library/ba-create-sql-reports-from-nosql-database-bluemix-trs/index.html?ca=drs-

Is this service deprecated? If yes, what is the alternative I can use to generate reports?

Thanks Raj

Answer (score 1):

The Embeddable Reporting Service was withdrawn from the Bluemix catalog on May 15, 2016. The service functionality has not been replaced with another Bluemix service.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill.